# How to create a video file out of bitmaps?

Tags: c#, bitmap, aforge

Is there any way for how to record the images into a video file (output.avi) by implementing some code inside the NewFrame event handler. Also how can we make the size of file not too much big?

I've got a pictureBox1 and a button1 and I'm using the code below to switch on the webcam and display the output on pictureBox1

The code works fine. However, I need to implement a way to **Save the output to a video file rather than showing it on the pictureBox**

I use the code below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
    videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame); 
    ///
    CloseVideoSource();         
    videoSource.Start();  
}


private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Bitmap img = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    pictureBox1.Image = img; // Something should go here to make the video file out of successive bitmaps ?
}

private void CloseVideoSource()
{
    if (!(videoSource == null))
        if (videoSource.IsRunning)
        {
            videoSource.SignalToStop();
            videoSource = null;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is to use the [VideoFileWriter](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/4ee1742c-44d3-b250-d6aa-90cd2d606611.htm) class. There's a nice [demo](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/ffmpeg.html) in the AForge.Net documentation.

Note that your code will need to include the FFMPEG dlls found in the Externals folder in your AForge installation directory.

Comment: Dear @rold2007, my program is less than 1 MB, bundling FFMPEG makes my program over 15MB. Is there anyway I can copress a video without bundling FFMPEG with my application ? I can now save AVI video to file. However the file is too big. 10 seconds is approx 30 MB ?

Comment: I don't think there's any other way while using AForge. You could try UPX (http://upx.sourceforge.net) to compress the FFMPEG dlls, see also this discussion http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=597. Video file size are dependent a lot on how much movement there is in the image. But you could still tweak it by changing the BitRate and Codec properties of the VideoFileWriter class. I'm no video expert so you'll have to figure out the best parameters yourself. You could also reduce the width and height of the video depending on your needs.